# Error al exportar datagridview a excel C#

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente error:

> Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
>   en mscorlib.dll
>
> Información adicional: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative
>   and less than the size of the collection.

En la siguiente linea de código:

```
   ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
```

El código completo es el siguiente:

```
for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
{
    ws.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
}


// storing Each row and column value to excel sheet
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
    }
}
ws.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

int crow = dataGridView1.Rows.Count; //empezamos donde termino


for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView2.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
{
    ws.Cells[crow, i] = dataGridView2.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
}
//empezamos desde crow + 1 y nos movemos dgv2.rows.count filas
for (int i = crow + 1; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count + crow - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
    }
}

// sizing the columns
ws.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que se guarden los datos de mis datagridview en una sola hoja de excel.

Ya he buscado el error, pero no encuntro que pueda ser.

Answer (score 1):

En la parte donde haces el ciclo para controlar las columnas con la variable `j` te falta restar 1 al `.Count`. Las dos líneas de código deben quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
```

Comment: En todos los for